# When can a complex function have non isolated singularities?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, entire-functions, meromorphic-functions

Given an entire function $f(z)$, why can $f(1/z)$ have at worst an isolated singularity at $0$? Can a meromorphic function have non isolated singularities? What about other kinds of functions?

I'm probably missing something very simple given that there are no questions on this site about this..

Comment: Because $f$ is entire.... So $f(1/z)$ is well-defined in a deleted neighbourhood of zero.

Comment: Does $f$ need to be entire for this?

Comment: By definition a pole is an isolated singularity; hence the singularities of a meromorphic function are isolated.

Answer (score 0):

By definition a meromorphic function is analytic except for isolated singularities which are poles. An example of a function with non-isolated singularity is $\frac 1 {\sin(\frac 1 z)}$. This function has singularites at each of the points $\frac 1 {n\pi}$ so $0$ is a non-isolated singularity.